2 hours for self transfer in Manchester?
We're two adults and two children (4 and 6) arriving from Shannon at 3:50pm with Ryanair. We would like to continue to Berlin at 5:55pm on easyjet. We have checked bags. Is it feasible to do at Manchester Airport? We're EU citizens.

Yikes. You would need lots of luck this make this.

isn't it easier to go to Dublin by bus and fly from there?

It's probably possible but extremely risky.
The check-in/bag drop deadline for your Easyjet flight to Berlin is 40 minutes before scheduled departure.
Also, the gate closes 30 minutes before departure.
That means you have at best 1h25 to:

Deplane
Get to baggage claim
Wait for your bags
Go through customs
Go from Terminal 3 arrivals to Terminal 1 departures
Find the check-in area for your flight
Queue and drop bags

After that, you will still need to:

Go through security
Get to your gate at the latest 30 minutes before departure.

So you should probably drop your bags a lot earlier than the deadline if you want to make it, unless you have fast track maybe.
While this is possible if all goes well, it's extremely risky (especially with children in tow), and any slight delay will disrupt your plans.
Remember that if you don't meet the deadlines you will be considered a "no show", and your tickets will be cancelled and will not be refundable, so you'll have to book and pay for new tickets on the spot, at last minute prices (usually a lot more expensive).
Easyjet do have a "rescue fee" (£110 per passenger!) where you can be booked on the next flight if you arrive within two hours of the deadline. It can actually be worth it in some cases.
Remember however that Easyjet only have 4 flights a week to BER, so you would need to wait until the next day or even the one after that (and hotels and meals and transfers would be for you to pay). You would probably need to use another airline.
Of course if you are travelling on a busy day, on top of the additional risk of delays, you have the risk of not being able to find 4 seats on a flight to your destination at the last minute.
I would most definitely not book that.

Thanks. The alternative is to go through Stansted with a 4 hour layover. Seems a lot more feasible I assume.

@8192K The usual rule of thumb is to have at least 4 hours between two flights in a self-transfer, but while that reduces the risk it does not remove it completely. Depending on the risk level (cost and frequency of the onward flight, mainly) a larger buffer may be warranted (but again, never completely removes the risk compared to an actual connection). But "real" connections on that route seem pretty lousy with veeeeeery long layovers :-(

Yes, and they are like 3 times more expensive.

@8192K It would probably be a good idea to have good travel insurance and check the exact terms for missed connections. What date are you travelling on?

It might even be sensible to buy two sets of tickets for the UK-Germany leg, the 4 hour and one after that.
